# O que faz um popup ser bloqueado?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, popup

Já percebi que algumas bibliotecas, como a de login com o facebook, sempre usam popups para a autenticação do usuário e, quase sempre, esse popup não é bloqueado.

Geralmente, quando o mesmo é aberto com um evento de click não há bloqueios. E quando usamos `window.open` diretamente no console, por exemplo, eles são bloqueados.

Como determinar as situações em que o popup será bloqueado?

Existe alguma maneira de driblar esse bloqueio? Ou existe alguma forma de "informar" que tal popup é "confiável" para abertura?

Answer (score 7):

Popups são bloqueadas por navegadores quando identificado uma ação `window.open` (ou equivalente) que não **aparenta** ser uma ação imediata do usuário. Os navegadores antigos poderiam considerar qualquer pilha de função como um mau sinal e optar por bloquear. Já na atualidade, o processo é mais sofisticado e examinará com um desempenho melhor a característica da chamada.

Um exemplo prático:

```
<body onload="abrir(true);">
    <button id="abcd" type="button" onclick="abrir(false)">Ação Direta</button>        
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function abrir(value) {
      if (value) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          window.open('http://pt.stackoverflow.com');
        }, 5000);
      } else {            
        window.open('http://pt.stackoverflow.com');
      }

    }
</script>
```

Mesmo sendo a mesma função e utilizando o Timeout para tentar enganar, o Google Chrome irá bloquear uma pop-up após 5 segundos do carregamento da página, no entanto nunca bloqueará o click do usuário.

Podemos simplificar a função e encontrar o mesmo comportamento:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abrir(value) {
      window.open('http://pt.stackoverflow.com');
    }
</script>
```

> O que faz um popup ser bloqueado?

A habilidade do navegador de determinar se a chamada à função `window.open` é de intenção do usuário ou não.

Comment: Em teoria, qualquer página que você for acessar, você poderá clicar para acessar o endereço, então... você pode disparar o evento do popup nessa hora.